# Javax mail api with OVH

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, ovh

Is it possible to user javax mail with OVH?
I can do it with Yahoo mail, but when I am trying to use it with OVH I am getting this error :

> at org.springframeworkjavax.mail.MessagingException: Exception
>   reading response;   nested exception is:  java.net.SocketException:
>   Connection reset

the connection properties are :

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
```

If anyone can see where I am wrong here...

Thanks.

Comment: The port for TLS should be 587, I have checked the site of OVH which refer this port number http://help.ovh.com/EmailConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

I tried successfully by using the TLD port 587 (as indicated by @Mo.Ashfaq above).

The documentation from OVH is visible here: http://help.ovh.com/EmailConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

This config works for me:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "ssl0.ovh.net");
properties.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```